# Conventions For Summary And Parameter Text?

Tags: c#, xml-documentation

For writing summary and parameter text, is there a best practice for how much detail you have to get into, whether or not to use complete sentences, or whatever?  I'm just looking for some good habits to establish as I start using these more.  Thanks!

```
public class JustinBieber{
    private readonly bool HasTalent;
    JustinBieber(){
        HasTalent = false;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// JustinBieber object sings a song in specified style
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="songName">The song to be sung</param>
    /// <param name="style">The style in which the song is sung</param>
    public void SingSong(string songName, string style){
        ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Jon Skeet's homepage has a link to a Java code convention page @oracle, that discusses this briefly, applied to Java of course. http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/java/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My rule of thumb here is to use enough detail to convey the meaning clearly, and no more.

I prefer conciseness here - and feel this is particularly important, as the XML documentation is used for intellisense.  Very long comments tend to not be visible easily there, so I would avoid them, and put the "longer" comments into `<remarks>` if needed.